# Javascript requiring an image or code breaks

Tags: javascript

I'm tinkering with code that I found for a simple little javascript slot machine.  That machine (with source code & images) can be found here:
http://www.coderprofile.com/networks/source-codes/239/slot-machine

Line 80 reads...

`<img src="blueline.gif"><br>`

If I remove that line, everything breaks.  If I duplicate that line, the first image in the reels gets sent over to the 2nd "img src=blueline"

ETA: I can remove the source (so it just says img) or give the image a hidden style and the code continues to work.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Well that's some terrible code...

Comment: `eval("document.slots."+slot+".value="+val+";");` --- man, do you know the square bracket notation? Use `document.slots[slot].value=val`. Eval is evil and dangerous.

Comment: I didn't write that particular code. Just trying to work with it.  Thanks for the heads up on eval.
I finally figured out the issue. I'll edit my question with what I did.

Comment: I apologize for this but, could someone please tell me how to mark this question as resolved so it's not in the way of others?

Comment: Answer to yourself, wait for 24 hours, accept the answer. You can add a `[resolved]` tag to the title in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I'll do that asap.  I'm brand new to posting here so it's making me wait awhile.  Again, I thank you for your time.  And now I'm going to go read up on eval to see what I can do to avoid "evil and dangerous."

Comment: This code uses `eval` to replace the square bracket notation with a dot notation, and introduces a potential bug in the process (namely, if the `val`ue needs string-escaping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed line 14 from

`document.images[img].src=val+".jpg";`

to

`document["img"+img].src=val+".jpg";`

so that it would match the information being given at lines 41-43